# Azure AD restrict unassigned audience from accessing application

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-active-directory

I am new to Azure AD B2B, I created an Application in Azure Active Directory.

**Home -> Default Directory -> App registrations -> New Registration** and selected an audience as **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox) **

the problem is all school or personal accounts(whether assigned or not to the application) are autenticated using **Microsoft.Identity.Client** liberary and token is generated, but I wanted to restrict the users from accessing it. All the assigned users can only access the application. But its not happening even I set **user assignment required** option to **YES**. Any iser who is not even assign to the applpication is getting authenticated and token is generated insted and error message should be thrown that permission is not granted.

Note: I am using Xamarin.Forms as a client application

Answer (score 0):

The result sounds logical.
You said *any* Azure AD tenant / personal account can access the app.
So any account is allowed access.
*User assignment required only applies to your AAD tenant*.
When a personal account signs in, they sign in with their personal account and your AAD tenant is never involved.

If you want control over who accesses the app,
you need to change the app to single-tenant (i.e. only allow accounts from this directory).